# How to Interrupt and stop a message download stream in Thunderbird without resuming later

Tags: thunderbird

I accidentally clicked Get All Messages in Thunderbird when I intended to get only one user's messages.  One user had more than 4,000 messages to download, and I don't want to get them now, and probably ever unless this computer crashes. They will expire on the server. I disconnected Thunderbird after 943 had downloaded, and I do not want the remaining 3,000+ to download.  Is there a way to stop the message download midstream and not have it resume when I reconnect?

Comment: Huh? You've got multiple users using one instance of Thunderbird?!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand what's going on...but you could go to `Account Settings` and go to the `Server Settings` under the account you are talking about. Then un-check `Automatically download new messages`.